How do I match text between angle brackets in Typst?
I am using the following regex:
#show regex("<.+>"): highlight

But it doesn't work. A single < correctly matches angle brackets but as soon as I type any other character it doesn't match anything. For example, I have the following text:
\<20...

But the regex <20 doesn't match this either.
MWE
#show regex("<.*>"): highlight

\<#lorem(10)\>

Expected output:

Actual output


You mean there can be no <? Try <[^<>]*>?

@WiktorStribiżew no it doesn't work either.

I cannot reproduce your issue. For me it works here. Please provide a minimal working example of some input and preferably the corresponding expected output. Escaped \< for me throws an error for the string already, so it might not be an issue with regex.

@DuesserBaest added MWE

It turns out this is a well-known bug in Typst. See here.

I would suggest that the < (and possibly the >) character are "reserved characters", these carry special meaning unless "escaped". You would need to know what regular expression engine Typst uses, check it's documentation on "reserved characters". When using one of these reserved characters, to actually mean the character, not the special meaning you need to "escape" the character. This may mean preceding the character by the escape character, for me that would be "\".
I checked Perl regex as an example (see Perl Boost documentation.
Down lower on that page the < refers to a start of a word and > the end of a word. Generally a "word" is a mixture of a-z and 0-9, but no spaces, it may also contain some other characters.
If I'm right I'd adjust your regex to be:
"\<.+\>"

It's written in Rust and it uses this crate for regexes. I know that < is a reserved character but escaping it also doesn't work and there's no mention of it on the crate help page.

Use the Example link (down about 1 page) within that crate link. That will then show some examples and below that is reference to "raw strings" and use of escape character. It seems (to me) reading that sentence that if not using raw string you need to "double escape" on reserved characters to make it literal.
